# group by count(*) mysql multiple tables

Tags: mysql

Im trying to do a count(*) across multiple tables, but put them in a group by.

My query in mysql is:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(*) as 'Orders', Customer FROM table WHERE `date` = CURRENT_DATE()) as Client1, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) as 'Orders', Customer FROM table2 WHERE `date` = CURRENT_DATE()) as Client2,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) as 'Orders', Customer FROM table3 WHERE `date` = CURRENT_DATE()) as Client3
  group by Customer
```

This is what I am trying to get back:

```
+-------------+---------+---------+---------+
| Customer    | Client1 | Client2 | Client3 |
+-------------+---------+---------+---------+
| John Doe    | 88      | 19      | 0       |
+-------------+---------+---------+---------+
| Mary P      | 0       | 32      | 0       |
+-------------+---------+---------+---------+
| Scott K     | 11      | 25      | 31      |
+-------------+---------+---------+---------+
```

My only other concern is that the customers will not exist in other tables, for example - John Doe is only a customer in table1 - not table2 or table3.

Same with Mary P - she is only a customer in table2 not table1 or table 3 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select a.Customer, sum(client1), sum(client2), sum(client3)
from
(
    select Customer, count(*) as client1, 0 as client2, 0 as client3 from table WHERE `date` = CURRENT_DATE() group by Customer
    union all
    select Customer, 0, count(*), 0 from table2 WHERE `date` = CURRENT_DATE() group by Customer
    union all
    select Customer, 0, 0, count(*) from table3 WHERE `date` = CURRENT_DATE() group by Customer
) as a
group by a.Customer
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `()` before the union all 
like

```
  select a.Customer, sum(client1), sum(client2), sum(client3)
    from
    (
        (select Customer, count(*) as client1, 0 as client2, 0 as client3 from table WHERE `date` = CURRENT_DATE() group by Customer)
        union all
        (select Customer, 0, count(*), 0 from table2 WHERE `date` = CURRENT_DATE() group by Customer)
        union all
        (select Customer, 0, 0, count(*) from table3 WHERE `date` = CURRENT_DATE() group by Customer)
    ) as a
    group by a.Customer
```